# Get selected object, rather than bound value, from Autocomplete

Tags: blazor, telerik, blazor-webassembly

I am using the Telerik Autocomplete in a slightly unorthodox way and am facing a challenge. I try to make the code below as self-explanatory as possible.

```
<TelerikAutoComplete Data="@AddressSuggestions" Size="sm"
                 ValueChanged="@(async value => await OnAddressSearch(value, CancellationToken.None))"
                 ValueExpression="@(() => SearchAddressTerm)"
                 OnChange="@AddressSelectedHandler" Placeholder="Start typing address"
                 ClearButton="true" Filterable="false">
@code{
    public string SearchAddressTerm { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public AddressDisplays[] AddressSuggestions { get; set; } = Array.Empty<AddressDisplays>();
    public record AddressDisplays(string Value, string Text, string Type, int Count, string Id);

    private async Task OnAddressSearch(string searchTerm, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    {

     SearchAddressTerm  = searchTerm; 

     // API call using the user-typed searchTerm
     // retrieve address data 
     // create AddressDisplays object for each retrieved address - Value = searchTerm, Text = a display text for each address 
     // this way the AddressSuggestions[] is built up  
    }

     private async Task AddressSelectedHandler(object selectedAddressSearchTerm) 
     {
    // I need the obtain the actual selected AddressDisplays object, so I can continue processing of the selected address
     }
}
```

Basically, my bound value is the user input (searchTerm) in the Autocomplete box, because upon every key strike I need to call a third-party API using this user input as a parameter. This happens in OnAddressSearch and it works well.

The bound data (in the dropdown) is a string of objects (AddressDisplays), with Text being a string that displays the addresses. At the moment Value is again the searchTerm, but it doesn't need to be I guess.

**Problem:**
When the user selects an item from the dropdown, firing the OnChange event, it passes the current search term (user input) to AddressSelectedHandler. What I need is to obtain the actual selected AddressDisplays object instead.

I could change the Value in the AddressDisplays object to be anything else, like the Id of the address, but then this Id would fill in the text field, showing the user some "gibberish" they don't care about, and I really don't want this. Also I think I do need the entire object to process the rest of the logic.

Comment: If you want to be able to select an object from a list, then have a `MyObjectClass? SelectedObject {get; set;} = null;`.  In the appropriate even handler, find your Object based on the associated key and assign it to `SelectedObject`.  Be wary of overworking 3rd-party solutions-- they are there only to save time (since making components in Blazor is so darned easy).  So if you find them wasting time, dump them.

Comment: Make `AddressSuggestions` a `Dictionary<AddressObject, AddressSuggestion>` and then do a lookup on the dictionary in `AddressSelectedHandler`.